# Pass a variable to a file using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook yml file in which I am calling multiple tasks, which deploys the files to servers. e.g. my ansible playbook file below

```
tasks:
     - name: "Deploy employee file"
     include: deploy_employee.yml unit_file={{item}}
     with_items: "{{ employee_files }}"
     when: Action == ("employee")
```

In vars.yml, i have the below

```
employee_files:
  - 'employee_deployment.service'
```

The employee_deployment.service file looks like below

```
[service]
User=emp
Group=emp
Start=/bin/bash -c 'exec /home/tools/$env/emp.sh start >> /logs/emp/emp.log 2>&1'
```

My problem is I am unable to replace/update 'env' variable above, basically I would need three values as dev, test and prod depending on the environment. How to update dynamically if we pass the variable through command line for example.

I have tried sending the value from command line using below

ansible-playbook ansible_playbook.yml -e "Action='employee'" -e "env='dev'" but the value didn't get updated in the .service file. Also, I didn't get any error too. Could anyone please guide me to correct direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide and show your `deploy_employee.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) to  substitute the variable *env* in the file *employee_deployment.service*

```ini
shell> cat employee_deployment.service
[service]
User=emp
Group=emp
Start=/bin/bash -c 'exec /home/tools/{{ env }}/emp.sh start >> /logs/emp/emp.log 2>&1'
```

In the included tasks, parse the file. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat deploy_employee.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', item) }}"

- set_fact:
    data: "{{ lookup('template', item)|community.general.jc('ini') }}"

- debug:
    var: data
```

Note: You'll need [jc](https://pypi.org/project/jc/) on the controller

---

gives (limited to a single host)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    [service]
    User=emp
    Group=emp
    Start=/bin/bash -c 'exec /home/tools/dev/emp.sh start >> /logs/emp/emp.log 2>&1'

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************
ok: [host_1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  data:
    service:
      Group: emp
      Start: /bin/bash -c 'exec /home/tools/dev/emp.sh start >> /logs/emp/emp.log 2>&1'
      User: emp
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── deploy_employee.yml
├── employee_deployment.service
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── vars.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: deploy_employee.yml
      loop: "{{ employee_files }}"
      when: Action == 'employee'
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars.yml 
employee_files:
  - employee_deployment.service
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e Action=employee -e env=dev -l host_1 pb.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************************
included: /scratch/test-537/deploy_employee.yml for host_1 => (item=employee_deployment.service)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    [service]
    User=emp
    Group=emp
    Start=/bin/bash -c 'exec /home/tools/dev/emp.sh start >> /logs/emp/emp.log 2>&1'

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************
ok: [host_1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  data:
    service:
      Group: emp
      Start: /bin/bash -c 'exec /home/tools/dev/emp.sh start >> /logs/emp/emp.log 2>&1'
      User: emp

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

You can simplify the tasks

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  vars:

    data: "{{ lookup('template', item)|community.general.jc('ini') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          Group: {{ data.service.Group }}
          Start: {{ data.service.Start }}
          User: {{ data.service.User }}
      loop: "{{ employee_files }}"
      when: Action == 'employee'
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e Action=employee -e env=dev -l host_1 pb.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => (item=employee_deployment.service) => 
  msg: |-
    Group: emp
    Start: /bin/bash -c 'exec /home/tools/dev/emp.sh start >> /logs/emp/emp.log 2>&1'
    User: emp

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir for the solution. I will try the same and let you know the updates. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I am not able to install jc due to system level constraints. Is there any other way to substitute the variable value in the .service file without using jc

Comment: Or without using jinja

Comment: You can [parse](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html) the data on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see a lot of parsing options available there but could you please point me to the right parser which will not require any additional things to be installed like jc.

Comment: Ok thanks Vladimir, I will figure out this piece.